# Tableau-error while connecting to oracle DB

Tags: oracle, tableau-api

I'm trying to use Tableau Desktop version 8, an IT statistics S/W.
I've to connect it my enterprise DB.

It asks for Server name, service name and port.
I'm giving the host name(abc.xyz.com) for the server name.
I'm putting the other two as is, copying directly from my SQL developer.

I'm giving the user name/pwd too for the schema authentication.

But while trying to connect it just gives me an error "Unable to connect to server, check that server is running and you have the required previlages".

I'm able to connect to the DB easily from SQL developer.

I'f someone has faced this issue, kindly help me out.

Thanks
Sagar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a first pass, my suspicion would be that a 64-bit driver is being used instead of a 32-bit driver. Try [downloading and installing the officially supported driver](http://www.tableausoftware.com/support/drivers) and see if that resolves your issue.